# how to setup ipython for scrapy debug

Tags: scrapy, ipython

When running `scrapy shell [url]` command i can use fetch() and other scrapy stuff all in ipython environment. What do i need to setup in ipython to be able run all scrapy shell methods in ipython?

Answer (score 0):

Through scrapy’s settings you can configure it to use any one of ipython, bpython or the standard python shell, regardless of which are installed. This is done by setting the SCRAPY_PYTHON_SHELL environment variable; or by defining it in your scrapy.cfg:

[settings]
shell = bpython

Comment: 1. thanks. this is useful info. 2. i'm questioning an other thing - how to load scrapy fetch method into  pure ipython. which modules should i import to have all scrapy debug. that q is of my curiosity. i know about scrapy shell command